# How to loop through entries in nodes definition for puppet

Tags: puppet

Could someone please help me understand how I could loop through the following nodes definition in my templates file?

```
ip::addr{ "as2s67v":
    ip0 => "192.168.30.0",
    pre0 => "/24",
    ip1 => "172.45.35.0",
    pre1 => "/16",
    ip2 => "145.88.88.0",
    pre2 => "/24",
}
```

I'd like to print out the above using my template file, however I can't be certain of how many entries will exist, I want to end up with a file like so:

```
server: as2s67v
ipaddress0 = "192.168.30.0"
prefix0 = "24"
ipaddress1 = "172.45.35.0"
prefix1 = "16"
ipaddress2 = "145.88.88.0"
prefix2 = "24"
```

How could I go about achieving this?

thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but it cuts down on having to keep multiple variables in sync:

site.pp:

```
class { 'ip::addr':
  name  => "as2s67v",
  cidrs => [ "192.168.30.0/24", "172.45.35.0/16", "145.88.88.0/24" ]
}
```

modules/ip/addr.pp:

```
class ip::addr ($cidrs) {
  file { "/tmp/$name":
    content => template("ip/template.pp")
  }
}
```

template.pp:

```
server: <%= name %>
<% for idx in (0..(cidrs.length-1)) -%>
ipaddress<%= idx %> = "<%= cidrs[idx].split("/")[0] %>"
prefix<%= idx %> = "<%= cidrs[idx].split("/")[1] %>
<% end -%>
```

References:

- [How do you pass an array to an erb template in ruby and have it iterated over?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080147)
- [Nested arrays in puppet](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/VU41XeSqFeo/1eNQ71HU8gUJ)